# What is "operator int&() { return i; } " doing in the code

Tags: c++

I came across this code just few minutes back here in Stack Overflow.
I was confused about what actually  `operator int&() { return i; }` is doing in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class INT {
public:
            INT(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
            operator int&() { return i; }
            void display()
            {
              cout << "value of i is : " << i;       
            }
private:
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  INT l;
  cin >> l;
  l.display();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

I added the display function just to get some insight. I saw that the value that I get from `cin >> l;` gets assigned to `i` which is private member of object `l`. So this is 
some sort of overloading definitely I guess.

Can you let me know can we take the value of the object of class from directly through `cin`? Does it work fine?

What if I have two `int` variables in private part of my `class INT`?

Comment: Why not **try** it and see what happens?

Comment: @KerrekSB I added a new variable in private part . The `i` was assigned the value that i gave as input from my console and second Variable gives O/P as zero as i initialized it to be so. How can i get both the variables get input from console ?

Comment: Try defining *two* conversion operators; GCC gives me a very clear and helpful error message in that case.

Comment: @KerrekSB you mean one of `int` type and other of say `char` type ?

Comment: Please remove that conio.h include unless you want to bring the wrath of MS-DOS gods upon yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **What is `operator int&() { return i; }` doing in the code?**

It is a **[Conversion Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383606/conversion-operators-in-c)**; it takes in an `INT` object and returns a reference to `int` type.

One implicit conversion is always allowed whenever the compiler can match function arguments etc.
So, whenever there is a function which takes an `int` but an `INT` instance is passed to it, the compiler uses this conversion operator to convert an `INT` to `int`, so that appropriate conversion takes place and function can be called.

> **What is the use of such conversion. Are they helpful in practical code?**

As said in the first answer, this is useful whenever your code needs a lot of implicit conversions.
Note that in the absence of such a feature, one would have to provide special member functions which return appropriate types and the user will have to call them explicitly; this is lot of coding overhead, which is avoided by this feature.

> **Can you let me know can we take the value of the object of class from directly through `cin`?   Does it work fine?**

In order that `cin>>l` should work,
`l` should be of a data type for which the `>>` operator is overloaded for type `cin`(`istream`)

Note that `>>` is overloaded for most of the built-in data types, and hence you can directly use,
`cin>>i`, for types where `i` is `int` or `float` and so on.

However, in your example,
`l` is of the type `INT` and `>>` operator is not overloaded for the `INT` data type. Of course `INT` is your custom class and the standard C++ library implementation could not know of it while implementing overloads for `>>` and hence no overload exists for it.
Since there is no overloaded version of `>>` available, you cannot directly use `>>` and the compiler will return an error of no matching function.

You will have to provide an **[overload >> operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719)** as an free standing function, receiving an `INT`, to be able to use `cin>>l`.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, INT& obj) 
{

}
```

Comment: is it actually returning the object ? I guess in my code its returning just private member `i of INT ` class . My doubt is mainly about can we take object members value like `cin >> l;` as declared in main (). Also what if i have 2 or three different private integer value . What in that case ?

Comment: @Ritesh: In that case, you would write a custom stream extraction and insertion operator for the class.

Comment: @Als What is the use of such conversion . Are thy helpful in practical code?

Comment: @Ritesh: I have updated to answer all your queries, hope that helps.

Comment: "One implicit conversion is always allowed" -- this part is not really correct, since it's one implicit conversion *sequence*, which may either be a standard conversion sequence or a user-defined conversion sequence.. but for someone who doesn't know what conversion operators are, this may be a bit too much language lawyering. :)

Comment: @Als Thanks a lot Als . This solves all my issue. I wrote :-
`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, INT& obj) 
  {
    obj.setvalue();
  }`

and 
`void setvalue()
  {
    cin >> i; 
    cin >> k;      
  }` 
and it worked fine and took the input of both the variables from console and displayed them too :)

Comment: The setvalue is very ugly. Use friend function instead: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function