# Boost tribool usage

Tags: c++, boost, tribool

That is my sample of testing boost::tribool:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/logic/tribool.hpp"

int main()
{
boost::logic::tribool init;
//init = boost::logic::indeterminate;
init = true;
//init = false;

if (boost::logic::indeterminate(init))
{
    std::cout << "indeterminate -> " << std::boolalpha << init << std::endl;
}
else if (init)
{
    std::cout << "true -> " << std::boolalpha << init << std::endl;
}
else if (!init)
{
    std::cout << "false -> " << std::boolalpha << init << std::endl;
}

bool safe = init.safe_bool(); <<---- error here
if (safe) std::cout << std::boolalpha << safe << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use safe_bool() function to convert boost::tribool to plain bool but have complile time error:

```
Error   1   error C2274 : 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator D : \install\libs\boost\boost_samples\modules\tribool\src\main.cpp  23  1   tribool
```

Looks like i am using safe_bool() function incorrectly.
Could you help me resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`safe_bool` is a type, i.e., the function `operator safe_bool()` converts a `tribool` to a `safe_bool`. If you simply what to convert to a regular `bool` use: `bool safe = init;`. `safe` will in this case be `true` if and only if `init.value == boost::logic::tribool::true_value`.

Answer (score 2):

That [`safe_bool` "method"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/logic/tribool.html#idp18436832-bb) is not a normal method, but a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444591/what-is-operator-int-return-i-doing-in-the-).

```
BOOST_CONSTEXPR operator safe_bool() const noexcept;
//              ^^^^^^^^
```

The conversion operator means the `tribool` will act like a `bool` when a boolean is requested, so you just need to write:

```
bool safe = init;  // no need to call anything, just let the conversion happen.

// or just:
if (init) { ... }
```

---

You should notice that the operator returns a `safe_bool`, not a `bool`. `safe_bool` here is actually an internal member-function-pointer type:

```
class tribool
{
private:
  /// INTERNAL ONLY
  struct dummy {
    void nonnull() {};
  };

  typedef void (dummy::*safe_bool)();
```

It is written like this following the [**safe bool idiom**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool#Solution_and_Sample_Code) ([which is obsolete in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11)).

What is important it that the pointer is non-null when the `tribool` is true, and null when the `tribool` is false or indeterminate, so we could sort-of treat the result like a boolean.