# C++ Templates and operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning templates and operator overloading. I have written some code but I am confused... Let me explain...

```
template <class T>
class tempType 
{
public:
    T value;
    bool locked;

    tempType():locked(false)
    { 
        value = 0; 
    }

    T operator=(T val)
    { 
        value=val;
        return value; 
    }
    tempType<T> operator=(tempType<T> &val)
    { 
        value=val.value; 
        return *this; 
    }
    operator T()
    { 
        return value; 
    }
};
```

And I did...

```
int main(void)
{
    tempType<int> i;
    tempType<bool> b;
    tempType<float> f;
    i.value = 10;
    i = i + f;
    return 0;
}
```

What code I need to write in order to execute

```
tempType<T> operator=(tempType<T> &val){}
```

Also, I why `operator T()` is required?

Comment: That parameter should be `const`.

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but to override default `operator=` you should define it as `tempType<T> operator=(const tempType<T> &val){}`. Now you need to call the method explicitly via `i.operator=(other_i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class tempType 
{
public:
    T value;
    bool locked;

    tempType() : value(), locked(false)
    { 
        value = 0; 
    }

    //althought legal, returning something different from tempType&
    //from an operator= is bad practice
    T operator=(T val)
    { 
        value=val;
        return value; 
    }
    tempType& operator=(const tempType &val)
    { 
        value=val.value; 
        return *this; 
    }
    operator T()
    { 
        return value; 
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    tempType<int> a;
    tempType<int> b;
    a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

in the code, `a = b` calls the operator.

As for the second question, the `operator T()` is not needed "by default". In your example, it is used when you write `i+f`:

1. `i` is converted to an int
2. `f` is converted to a float
3. the operation (+) is performed
4. `T tempType<int>::operator=(T val)` is called for the assignement

Comment: I edited the answer. The operator is used whenever a object of your type needs to be converted to a T

Answer (score 2):

I think I know all the answers so I might as well post full response.

To override default `operator=` you should declare it as `tempType<T> operator=(const tempType<T> &val){}`. Now you need to call the method explicitly via `i.operator=(other_i).`

If you correct the declaration you can use it like this:

```
tempType<int> i;
tempType<int> other_i;
i = other_i; // this is what you just defined
```

The `operator T()` is called a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383606/conversion-operators-in-c). It is kind of reverse or counter part of the [conversion constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905866/what-are-the-conversion-constructors) which in your case would be `tempType(const &T value)`.

It is used to convert a class object into a given type. So in your case you would be able to write:

```
tempType<int> i;
int some_int;
some_int = i; // tempType<int> gets converted into int via `operator int()`
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you implement move semantics, `operator=` should always take a `const &` reference to the source value. It should also return a reference to the modified object.

```
tempType & operator=(T const & val)
{ 
    value=val;
    return * this;
}
```

`operator T` is an implicit conversion function which allows any `tempType` object to be treated as an object of its underlying type `T`. Be careful when specifying implicit conversions that they won't conflict with each other.

An implicit conversion function usually shouldn't make a copy, so you probably want

```
operator T & ()
{
    return value; 
}

operator T const & () const
{
    return value;
}
```

Given these, you shouldn't need another overload of `operator =` because the first overload will simply be adapted by the conversion function to a call such as `i = b;`.

If a series of conversions will result in the `operator=(T const & val)` being called, you should avoid also defining `operator=(tempType const & val)` because the overloads will compete on the basis of which conversion sequence is "better," which can result in a brittle (finicky) interface that may refuse to do seemingly reasonable things.