# Can I automatically create a class instance from a numerical value where needed?

Tags: c++

Say I had a structure that represented a special numerical value, like a float with added functionality. This is just an example.

```
struct MyCustomFloat {

    MyCustomFloat(float value);
    MyCustomFloat(double value);

    ...
};
```

Then I had other functions that used instances of that struct. Another example.

```
MyCustomFloat add(MyCustomFloat x, MyCustomFloat y);
```

Is it possible to implement a way where I can give a int/float/double/etc. as my arguments for functions such as these and have them automatically converted to the custom type?

This way the messy code:

```
MyCustomFloat result = add(MyCustomFloat(1.5), MyCustomFloat(3.14));
```

Could be replaced with a cleaner:

```
MyCustomFloat result = add(1.5, 3.14);
```

And it would keep developers from having to write multiple versions of functions accepting each type of valid constructor input.

```
MyCustomFloat add(int x, int y);
MyCustomFloat add(float x, float y);
MyCustomFloat add(double x, double y);
MyCustomFloat add(int x, double y);
...
```

Comment: You can use conversion operator, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383606/conversion-operators-in-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could be replaced with:

It can, and you already halfway implemented it, because the constructors you already have will be used for [**implicit conversion**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:    
    A(float f) : val_(f) {}
    A(double d) : val_(d) {}

    A& operator+= (const A& r) {
        val_ += r.val_; 
        return *this;
    }

    double val() const  { return val_; }

private:    
    double val_;    
};

A add(const A& l, const A& r) {
    A a = l;
    a += r;
    return a;
}    

int main()
{
     std::cout << add(3.14f, 2.71).val() << std::endl;    
}
```

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c65d22f7745e4b8) at Coliru's**

*If that is however "cleaner" is a different topic; if that wasn't my own code and would just see `main()`, I would expect that an "add" adds a POD float and a POD double, and be surprised that the expected  result (POD) apparently has a fancy val member function all-of-a-sudden.*

Answer (score 0):

There several solutions to your problem:

- **overloaded functions:** give en implementation for each reasonable type and combinations of types. They should just convert the parameters and call the method with the `MyCustomFloat` parameters. In that case you do not need the overloaded Constructors.
- **operator:** implement `const MyCustomFloat MyCustomFloat::operator+(const MyCustomFloat &a)`. This way you can always use `a+b` as an expression, no matter what types they are. In that case you can write a single `add` function taking `MyCustomFloat` as arguments and they are constructed from your overloaded constructors. No need for overloaded `add` function here.
- **templates:** You will need a templated function for the general case, expecting the parameters to implement the `+` operator, i.e. being numerical types. Furthermore, you will need a template specialisation for `MyCustomFloat`. See example below. To mix types, you would need two templated types and three specialisations.

**Working example:**

```
#include <cstdio>

struct MyCustomFloat {

  double m_value;

public:

  MyCustomFloat(double a) : m_value(a){}
  double get() const {return m_value;}

  // uncomment this for use with operator+                                                                                   
  //const MyCustomFloat operator+(const MyCustomFloat &a) const {return m_value+a.get();}                                    
};

// use this whith operator+                                                                                                  
/*                                                                                                                           
MyCustomFloat add (const MyCustomFloat& a, const MyCustomFloat& b) {                                                         
  return MyCustomFloat(a+b);                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                            
/**/

// uncomment this for use with template                                                                                      
template <typename T>
MyCustomFloat add(const T& a, const T& b) {
  return MyCustomFloat(a+b);
}

template <>
MyCustomFloat add<MyCustomFloat> (const MyCustomFloat& a, const MyCustomFloat& b) {
  return MyCustomFloat(a.get()+b.get());
}
/**/

int main (void){
  printf("%f\n",add(1.2,3.4).get());
  printf("%f\n",add(MyCustomFloat(1.2),MyCustomFloat(3.4)).get());
  return 0;
}
```